# Mathematica Reference Book on Reliability Engineering?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, physics, reference-request

Can anyone suggest a reference book titled “Reliability Engineering Using Mathematica” or similar that contains the version 9 or version 10 functionality ?

Some topics/chapters I would be interested in are:

Accelerated Life Testing,
Bayesian Methods,
Critical Systems (medical devices, nuclear power, aerospace, etc.),
Degradation Analysis and Modeling,
Derating,
Design for Environments,
DFR,
DOE,
ESS and other Manufacturing Screens,
Failure Mode Modeling,
Fault Tolerant/Redundancy/Voting Trade Offs,
Fault/Success Trees,
Financial Analysis & Cost Trade Studies,
FMEA,
HALT/HASS,
Hardware Reliability,
Life Cycle Costing,
Life Data Analysis,
Maintainability/Availability Theory/Applications,
Markov Analysis,
Modeling Series, Parallel, K of N and Complex Systems,
RBDs,
Reliability Apportionment,
Reliability Growth Testing,
Reliability Prediction,
Risk Management,
Software Reliability (white box/black box),
Survivability,
System Safety,
Test Unit Sample Size Computations wrt Confidence Limits and
Warranty Analysis.

If no such books exist in this domain, any pointers to freely available papers from industry or academia would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know there's no reference book available yet that is using the new reliability functionality in Mathematica.

Two other resources are:

[Reliability calculations for complex systems, academic thesis](http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2:433387)

[Reliability Mathematics, Wolfram Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/09/30/reliability-mathematics-in-mathematica)

Those two focus on RBDs, Fault trees and system structures.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of these two resources and they are useful for what they focus on and are good first steps but the discipline of reliability engineering is quite vast as my original post tries to indicate and these address a small corner of the domain-space. Many thanks.